# How to use ngfor to iterate objects

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5

Given this set of data I am looking to iterate them inside my html. To achieve this I tried a nested `ngfor` but unsuccessfully.

What I tried was to iterate the object twice with a nested `ngfor` but I get this error

> HabitRecordsComponent.html:8 ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ
>   supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only
>   supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Here's the object.

```
{
  "Sat Jan 05 2019": [
    {
      "completed": true,
      "frequency": [
        7,
        6,
        2,
        1
      ],
      "description": "Walk 100km",
      "color": "#E97825",
      "task_id": "00397030-182d-11e9-957b-79c872c75fe1"
    },
    {
      "completed": true,
      "frequency": [
        7,
        6,
        5,
        4,
        3,
        2,
        1
      ],
      "description": "Study 2",
      "color": "#F4ED59",
      "task_id": "31151be0-182e-11e9-957b-79c872c75fe1"
    },
    {
      "completed": true,
      "frequency": [
        7,
        6,
        5,
        4
      ],
      "description": "Home drinking food2",
      "color": "#00A651",
      "task_id": "9825ea00-182c-11e9-957b-79c872c75fe1"
    }
  ],
  "Mon Jan 07 2019": [
    {
      "completed": true,
      "frequency": [
        7,
        6,
        2,
        1
      ],
      "description": "Walk 100km",
      "color": "#E97825",
      "task_id": "00397030-182d-11e9-957b-79c872c75fe1"
    },
    {
      "completed": false,
      "frequency": [
        5,
        4,
        3,
        1
      ],
      "description": "Drink 4lt Water",
      "color": "#ED1E24",
      "task_id": "250350c0-182d-11e9-957b-79c872c75fe1"
    },
    {
      "completed": true,
      "frequency": [
        7,
        6,
        5,
        4,
        3,
        2,
        1
      ],
      "description": "Study 2",
      "color": "#F4ED59",
      "task_id": "31151be0-182e-11e9-957b-79c872c75fe1"
    },
    {
      "completed": true,
      "frequency": [
        7,
        4,
        3,
        2,
        1
      ],
      "description": "New habit 4",
      "color": "#912AD6",
      "task_id": "ab378180-182c-11e9-957b-79c872c75fe1"
    }
  ],
```

Here's my html code

```
<div class="records-calendar">
    <div class="records-container" *ngFor="let formattedHabit of formattedHabits"></div>
    <div class="" *ngFor="let habit of formattedHabit"></div>
</div>
```

Here is my ts at the component

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, } from '@angular/core';
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import * as moment from 'moment';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-habit-records',
  templateUrl: './habit-records.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./habit-records.component.css']
})
export class HabitRecordsComponent{
  @Input()
  habitsComplete:any;
  formattedHabits:any;





  constructor(private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef) { }

  ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
      this.formattedHabits = this.habitsComplete.map(item => ({
        activities: item.completed.map(activity => ({
          [activity.Completed_at]:{
            completed: activity.Completed,
            frequency: item.Frequency.values,
            description: item.Description,
            color: item.Color,
            task_id:item.Task_id,
          }
          })),
      }))
       this.formattedHabits = this.formattedHabits.reduce((r, { activities }) => {
        activities.forEach(o => Object
            .entries(o)
            .forEach(([k, v]) => (r[k] = r[k] || []).push(v))
        );
        return r;
    }, {});
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to see the code of your component. Your component requires a public variable named 'formattedHabits' which should be an array of some sort of object representing the data structure you described.

In case you want to use the json as in your question, you may want to create a public variable 'formattedHabits' of type any and use JSON.Parse to convert the json object to a javascript object.

```
const formattedHabits: any = JSON.Parse('your json');
```

Then about your nested loop, you need to nest the divs as well.

```
<div class="records-container" *ngFor="let formattedHabit of formattedHabits">
    <div class="" *ngFor="let habit of formattedHabit.habits">{{habit.description}}</div>
</div>
```

This loop wil fail. In your question however you loop through an object which is not a collection.

Take a peek at my code, this will run a nested loop and display the description of each single habit.

And as a bonus, you're writing typescript. You benefit it's capabilities when not declaring all variables as any, but assign they're actual type.

Answer (score 0):

`ngFor` can only iterate over 'iterables', `formattedHabits` isn't currently iterable. You could change it to an array (which is iterable) like this:

```
{ "dateHabits": [   
    {
      "date": "Sat Jan 05 2019",
      "habits": [
        {
          "completed": true,
          "frequency": [
            7,
            6,
            2,
            1
          ],
          "description": "Walk 100km",
          "color": "#E97825",
          "task_id": "00397030-182d-11e9-957b-79c872c75fe1"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Please explain WHY it should be an array. Clearly the OP doesn't know that ngFor iterates arrays.